# If the transitivity of normality holds in a group $G$, then $G$ is an abelian group?

Tags: group-theory

I would like to know the answer to following question: Is it true that if $G$ is a group such that $N\triangleleft M$ and $M\triangleleft G$ then $N\triangleleft G$, for all subgroups $N,M$ of $G$, then $G$ is an abelian group?

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: No: there are groups in which every subgroup is normal but the group is not abelian (known as Dedekind groups). $Q_8$ is an example. Such a group satisfies your condition.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Groups with the property that $N\triangleleft M\triangleleft G$ implies $N\triangleleft G$ are sometimes called $t$-groups (or $T$-groups). (*Added:* More recent literature with access to a wider variety of typeface seems to use $\mathfrak{T}$-group).

For two trivial examples of $t$-groups that are not abelian:

1. Any nonabelian simple group is a $t$-group, since we must have $M=G$ or $M=\{e\}$.
2. Any [Dedekind group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dedekind_group) (groups in which every subgroup is normal) is a $t$-group. The quaternion group of order $8$ is an example of a nonabelian Dedekind group.

The name "$t$-group" seems to have been introduced by Olga Taussky and Ernest Best, in *A class of groups*, Proc. Roy. Irish Acad. Sect. A **47** (1942) 52-62, MR0006539 (4,2b). They proved that a finite $p$-group is a $t$-group if and only if it is abelian or a Dedekind group, and that a group is a $t$-group if it can be generated by elements $p_1,\ldots,p_n,q$ such that $p_i^m=q^n=1$, $p_ip_j = p_jp_i$, and $p_iq = qp_i^r$ where $\gcd(n,m)=1$, and $rn\equiv 1 \pmod{m}$; in particular, groups with all $p$-Sylow subgroups cyclic are $t$-groups.

Giovanni Zacher (*Caratterizzazione die $t$-gruppi finiti risolubili*, Ricerche Mat. **1** (1952), 287-294, MR0053104 (14,722b)) studied the finite soluble $t$-groups, and shows that a finite soluble group $G$ of order $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$, $p_1\gt\cdots\gt p_k$, is a $t$-group if and only if (i) all Sylow subgroups are abelian or Dedekind groups; and (ii) $G$ has a sequence $S_1,S_2,\ldots,S_k$ of Sylow subgroups, $S_i$ of order $p_i^{a_i}$, such that every $s_i\in S_i$ conjugates elements of $S_j$, $j\lt i$, into powers of themselves. (In particular, this would hold for groups in which all Sylow subgroups are cyclic).

Wolfgang Gaschütz gave an alternative characterization in *Gruppen, in denen das Normalteilersein transitiv ist*, J. Reine Angew. Math. **198** (1957), 87-92, MR0091277 (19,940b): If $G$ if finite and solvable, then $G$ is a $t$-group if and only if there exists $L\triangleleft G$ such that $L$ is abelian of odd order, $\gcd(|L|,|G/L|)=1$, $G/L$ is a Dedekind group, and conjugation induces power automorphisms in $L$. (In particular, a subgroup of a finite solvable $t$-group is necessarily a $t$-group).

Derek J.S. Robinson studied the infinite solvable case in *Groups in which normality is a transitive relation*, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. **60** (1964), 21-38, MR0159885 (28 #3101). He proved that a solvable $t$-group is necessarily metabelian (there is an abelian normal subgroup $M$ such that $G/M$ is also abelian); that finitely generated solvable $t$-groups are either finite or abelian; and that if $G$ is a torsion $t$-group and $C$ is the centralizer of $[G,G]$, then $[G:C]$ countable implies that $G$ splits over $[G,G,G]$.

A few years later, in *A note on finite groups in which normality is transitive*, Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. **19** (1968), 933-937, MR0230808 (37 #6366), Robinson proved that the following are equivalent for finite groups: (i) $G$ is a solvable $t$-group; (ii) Every subgroup of $G$ is a $t$-group; (iii) Every subgroup of a $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$ of $G$ is normal in $N_G(P)$ for all primes $p$.

Comment: $t$-group is a reaaaaally bad name.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez: Agreed: blame Olga Taussky! (The more recent literature seems to use $\mathfrak{T}$-group...)

Comment: +1, I appreciate your literature studies as much as your expository work :)